# Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined Insert-Statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

I wonder why the following code returns an error and does not enter the data into the table. The POST values ​​are filled, I tested that with echo.

```
<?php session_start();
      require("mysql.php");
      $userid = $_SESSION["userid"];
      $stmt = $mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO kunde ( userid ,Vorname, Nachname, Straße, Hausnummer) VALUES ( :userid, :vorname, :nachname, :straße, :hausnummer)");
      $stmt->bindParam(":userid", $userid);
      $stmt->bindParam(":vorname", $_POST["vorname"]);
      $stmt->bindParam(":nachname", $_POST["nachname"]);
      $stmt->bindParam(":straße", $_POST["straße"]);
      $stmt->bindParam(":hausnummer", $_POST["hausnummer"]);
      $stmt->execute();
?>
```

The code block below is a working solution. Nevertheless, I would like to know the issue in the first code block.

```
<?php session_start();
      require("mysql.php");
      $userid = $_SESSION["userid"];
      $vorname = $_POST["vorname"];
      $nachname = $_POST["nachname"];
      $straße = $_POST["straße"];
      $hausnummer = $_POST["hausnummer"];

      $sql = "INSERT INTO kunde ( userid, Vorname, Nachname, Straße, Hausnummer) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
      $stmt= $mysql->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->execute([$userid, $vorname, $nachname,$straße ,$hausnummer]);      
?>
```

Comment: It looks correct to me. The only thing I can think of is that it may not like the `ß` character in the placeholder.

Comment: @aynber Yes, thank you very much! I should code the variables in english in the future.